# How to get XML structure and values again to output via XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, tree

Is it possible to get via XSL whole XML again ? to see its structure/tree and values ?

I face issue that XML is hidden and I need to transform the XML via XSL to some HTML therefore I would like to to write xsl to get the input XML and check all available elements and values .

Matt

Comment: You want the exact XML or HTML? If the former, simply use the *identity transform*. If the latter, clarify.

Comment: You can copy the input how the XSLT processor sees it through to the output with e.g. `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>`. However, that way the XML has been parsed by an XML parser into the XSLT/XPath data model and is then serialized according to XSLT rules so you might encounter a perceived loss of lexical presentation like CDATA section, DTD info, entity and character references.

Comment: If you really wanted to see the XML within an HTML document, you could do something crude like this... `<xsl:template match="/"><textarea><xsl:copy-of select="." /></textarea></xsl:template>`

Comment: wau, thank you to all of you. It solved my question.